# How to align image in right bottom corner

Tags: html, css

How to places image in page bottom right corner.

```
<div id="background-img" class="background-img" ></div>

.background-img{
    background:url('images/bg-img.png');
    width:100%;
    height:698px; 
    repeat-x;
}
```

I created the background image with `1px` image. Now I have to I have to place company logo in page bottom right corner how to do this..

Any suggestion and how to code this one..  Advances Thanks...

Answer (score 32):

You could use absolute positioning:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion its almost there but the logo image is not exactly fitting in bottom of page right corner. it get placing 200px above of right corner. When page height getting increase the logo image is not going down. its remain same state.. my code: div class="background-img" img src="cmpy-logo" .background-img{ background:url('images/bg-img.png'); width:100%; height:698px; repeat-x; } cmpy-logo{ position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; }

Answer (score 13):

You can use `position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;` which makes sure that your company logo is always visible at bottom right corner - this means that page scrolling is not affecting its position.

or

You can use `position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;` which makes sure that your company logo is placed to a certain location and it is affected by the scrolling of the page.

I created a fiddle which demonstrates the differences, **[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YqR4h/56/)**

Comment: thanks for your suggestion its almost there but the logo image is not exactly fitting in bottom of page right corner. it get placing 200px above of right corner.

When page height getting increase the logo image is not going down. its remain same state..

my code:
div class="background-img"
img src="cmpy-logo"


.background-img{
    background:url('images/bg-img.png');
    width:100%;
    height:698px; 
    repeat-x;
}

cmpy-logo{

    position: absolute;
    bottom: -171px;
    right: 10px;
}

Comment: yea, just change position: absolute; to position: fixed; so it will go down when page is scrolled. if its 200px above of right corner: try adding margin: 0px; padding: 0px; for image style also. Edited my fiddle link to contain those styles.

Answer (score 3):

Use position fixed if you want your code to be positioned relative to window other wise ose position: absolute if you want it to position relative to document.

Relative to screen:

```
.background-img{

    position:fixed;
    right:10px;
    bottom: 10px 
}
```

Relative to document

```
.background-img{

    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    bottom: 10px 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```
 <div class="outer">
    <img src="....">
 </div>
```

with

```
 div.outer { position: relative; height: 24px; }
 div.outer img { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive this should also do it:

```
.background-img
{
   width:100%;
   height:698px; 
   background: url('images/bg-img.png') repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

There's also a background-position css property.

```
.background-img
{
   background:url('images/bg-img.png');
   width:100%;
   height:698px; 
   repeat-x;
   background-position: bottom right;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp